# VBA > UserForm > enter array of strings via any control

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Is there any control for UserForm that allows entering multiline text?
If no, any advice how to get array of strings entered manually via UserForm?

The only way after 5 minutes of brainstorming is to use TextBox + 'Add' Button to add entered strings to ListBox and then read content of the ListBox control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiline property of the textbox. Set it to true. Then you can split the text with new line into array. See below

```
Dim stringArray as Variant
stringArray = Split(txtBox1.Text, vbCr) ' You may use vbLf or vbCrlf
```

Comment: Maybe you could also mention changing the `EnterKeyBehavior` property. Otherwise multiline behaves counter-intuitively (at least to many people).

Answer (score 1):

Use TextBox, go to properties, set multiline = true

[image]